# Android WebDav library

Tags: android, webdav

I am looking for working WebDav library that I can use on Android. Sardine looked promising at first but I think that it is a no go on Android because it relies on apache http (this one can be resolved) but also on JAXB (which I am failing to resolve on Android). I have tried sardine-android but it is not working for me. When I try to connect to box.com using it I am getting `valuerequiredexception` on `getetag`. Any ideas on good library?

Comment: Hello! have you resolved the problem? Or, maybe, you have found another WebDAV lib for Android?

Comment: Hello, right now I am using owncloud library for android. It is library used to connect to owncloud but it works with every other webdav

Answer (score 5):

I've just released a fork of Sardine where I replaced JAXB (which is not included in Android platform) by SimpleXml and it seems to work well so far. Feel free to try it out and let me know if you have any issue: https://github.com/thegrizzlylabs/sardine-android